# How to find magnitude of the difference between y and the least squares fit?

Tags: matlab, least-squares, magnitude

I need to plot y using errorbar in matlab with error bars whose magnitude is the difference between y and the least squares fit. I have no idea how to find the magnitude.

```
y =

       60323
       61122
       60171
       61187
       63221
       63639
       64989
       63761
       66019
       67857
       68169
       66513
       68655
       69564
       69331
       70551
```

Can anyone help me how to do this in matlab or help me steer me in the right direction on where to start?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could look for information about the fitting here:
https://it.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/least-squares-fitting.html
Once you have a vector ydata with the fitted data you could take the difference between y and ydata, and take the absolute value